# Why does not `input` show up on python?

Tags: python

I am making simple game which there are 2 players and 20 sticks given. Each player can pick 1-3 stick(s) and player picks last stick will lose the game.

```
def stix(num):
    for _ in range(5): print('|  '* num)
    print
stix(20)
game_over = 0
while game_over !=0:
    players={}
    for i in range(2):
        players[i] = int(input('Player %d: Please pick stick(s) up to 3' %i))
        if players > 3 or players<0:
            print('Please pick between 1 - 3 stick(s)')
        else:
            stix-=players
            if stix <= 0:
                print('Player[i] lost')
                break
            else:
                print('There is %d stick(s) left' %stix)
                print(stix-players[i])
```

So, function `stix` shows 20 sticks and that's it. It does not ask `please pick stick(s) up to 3`. What did I miss in here?

*I am using python 2.6

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ErikGodard nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @ErikGodard - All that does in Python 2 is indicate grouping. It doesn't look like it'll make any difference in this particular case.

Comment: @ErikGodard does it matter? actually I have similar code that is fine with it. If I am wrong, please tell me.

Comment: @Jay, print() is preferred in Python 2.x to be forwards compatible. Also, I believe you should be using raw_input if you're using Python 2.x.

Comment: @Jay, also use `xrange` instead of `range` on Python 2.x. At this point, you might as well just use Python 3, really.

Comment: Aside from the question you asked there are many many other things that are horribly wrong about this code, like comparing dictionaries with integers, or making math operations between dictionaries and functions!!

Comment: @Emisor I bet. I just start learning programming and there are many mistake and misunderstand concept in my code. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never entering the while loop at all:

```
game_over = 0
while game_over !=0: # Evaluated to false the first time so it's skipped.
    # code
```

So the error, in this case, has nothing to do with `input()`

Comment: You might want to add an explanation, like "you set it to zero and then you only enter the block when it's not zero, so it doesn't get executed."

Comment: I'd make it `while game_over == 0:`, because wouldn't you want it to run until a game over occurs?

Comment: Considering what goes on inside that while loop, i'd rather not having it run at all...

Answer (score 0):

Your while case is that "game_over" does not equal 0 but the line directly above it sets it to 0.

I think what you want is:

```
game_over = True
while not game_over:
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `while` loop is going to run while game_over is **not** 0, but in the line before, you set `game_over` to 0.

```
game_over = 0
while game_over !=0:
    ...
```

Thus, change `game_over` to 1, and your code will work!

```
def stix(num):
    for _ in range(5): print('|  '* num)
    print
stix(20)
game_over = 1
while game_over !=0:
    players={}
    for i in range(2):
        players[i] = int(input('Player %d: Please pick stick(s) up to 3' %i))
        if players > 3 or players<0:
            print('Please pick between 1 - 3 stick(s)')
        else:
            stix-=players
            if stix <= 0:
                print('Player[i] lost')
                break
            else:
                print('There is %d stick(s) left' %stix)
                print(stix-players[i])
```

Comment: Actually he never uses `game_over` inside the loop at all. Instead, he `break`s out of the loop if any player loses. So, `while True` makes more sense, i think.